# dealing with list within list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following list :

```
[[[...],member,[...]],Header,[[...],member,[...]]].
```

which represents a binary search tree. This is my idea to build a Binary tree in Prolog, but the question is: how to access each list, and how to distinguish between them. And the most important question is: how to make a Variable 'point' (I use the concepts of C language to explain my idea) to the header of the tree, which is represented by Header.

Comment: i'm use SWI Prolog interpreter ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinguishing structure in Prolog is a matter of pattern matching. If we consider your binary tree structure:

```
[[[...],member,[...]],Header,[[...],member,[...]]]
```

As @ScottHunter pointed out, it has the form:

```
BinTree = [Left, Head, Right]
```

Where `Left` and `Right` are a binary tree structure defined recursively again as `[Left, Head, Right]`, `Head` represents a node value. I'm thinking this is what you intended...

Suppose you want to traverse the binary tree (*cf.* [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)) . You could use something like this to print all the nodes in left-to-right order:

```
inorder([L, H, R]) :-
    inorder(L),     % L is assumed to be of the form [L,H,R]
    write(H), nl,
    inorder(R).     % R is assumed to be of the form [L,H,R]
inorder([]).
```

Pre-order and post order simply follow the structure:

```
preorder([L, H, R]) :-
    write(H), nl,
    preorder(L),
    preorder(R).

postorder([L, H, R]) :-
    postorder(L),
    postorder(R),
    write(H), nl.
```

It's very simple and just follows the pattern. The knowledge of the structure of your tree is implicit in the code. Each branch is assumed to be of the form `[L, H, R]`, and an empty branch is `[]`. So a tree might look like: `[ [[], a, [[[],d,[]], e, []]], b, [[], c, []] ]`. This assumes that a node is null if it is the empty list, `[]`. For this case you'd get:

```
| ?- inorder( [ [[], a, [[[],d,[]], e, []]], b, [[], c, []] ]).
a
d
e
b
c
```

Note that no assumption in the predicates has been made about the structure of `Head`. It could, itself, be a list or any other kind of Prolog term. The only structural assumption is that a binary tree is a list of 3 items: a left subtree, a head, and a right subtree. A subtree is assumed to recursively be a binary tree. An empty tree is assumed to be an empty list `[]`.

To make a variable "point" to something, you do it through unification. For example:

```
BinTree = [ [[], a, [[[],d,[]], e, []]], b, [[], c, []] ]
```

Now `BinTree` is instantiated as the tree, and you can query `inorder(BinTree)` and get the results shown above. It can also be done in a predicate via the parameters:

```
unify(A, A).
```

If I query `unify(BinTree, [ [[], a, [[[],d,[]], e, []]], b, [[], c, []] ]).`, then `BinTree` will now be instantiated with `[ [[], a, [[[],d,[]], e, []]], b, [[], c, []] ]`.

Note that you probably want to avoid trying to think about Prolog using concepts and terms from procedural languages. It will lead you down the dark path of writing Prolog programs procedurally instead of declaratively, as it is intended to be used. And problems that should be easy to solve in Prolog will become difficult.

Comment: thank you so much , i have understand a lot from you explanation , i follow it in writing my code , and i become too close to solve my problem ,,,, (if this prolog a man , i will kill him) .

Comment: @Hassan with this attitude, no wonder that you are having problems.

Comment: @Boris I believe Hassan's comment was tongue-in-cheek intended to be humorous.

Comment: @Boris, i have an about 50 hours working on prolog , this is the first time that i deal with it , So it's naturally to have a problems.

Comment: @Hassan No one is born knowing, and we all go through the process one way or another. It is up to us how we go about it!

Comment: @Boris haha indeed. I see that now. That's the trouble with joking in SO comments. Hard to tell. It's all good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be a beginner to Prolog, an advice (rather than an answer):

It is not necessary to represent a tree as a recursively nested list. Instead, use a recursively nested term of arity 3, for example,

- `bst(Element, Left, Right)` for the tree term
- `empty` for the empty tree term

(bst here stands for binary search tree)

So a balanced tree representing [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] would be:

```
bst(4,
    bst(2,
        bst(1,
            empty,
            empty
        ),
        bst(3,
            empty,
            empty
        )
    ),
    bst(6,
        bst(5,
            empty,
            empty
        ),
        bst(7,
            empty,
            empty
        )
    )
)
```

You can look into the SWI-Prolog library [library(assoc)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/assoc.pl?show=src). It implements self-balancing binary trees using AVL, but you can read the code anyway: it is very clear and you don't need to go into the self-balancing if you don't want to. There is also a red-black tree implementation somewhere in the source tree of SWI-Prolog, it is available through the web page as well.

Apart from that, your question is very unclear and it is difficult to understand what is the exact problem you are facing, since you are not showing any code.

EDIT:

This is a non-deterministic predicate that checks if a value is in the tree, or enumerates values in increasing order:

```
bst_val(bst(_, Left, _), Val) :-
    bst_val(Left, Val).
bst_val(bst(Val, _, _), Val).
bst_val(bst(_, _, Right), Val) :-
    bst_val(Right, Val).
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate representation of the BST, Boris. I think it would be helpful to illustrate with a version of `traverse/1` using this representation.

Comment: @mbratch of course.... I guess the point is that any code I show here would be picked up from the SWI-Prolog assoc.pl, which I linked in the "answer" anyway. I will add a `gen_bst/2` anyway.

Comment: Boris, a list is an alternative representation per standard English usage, in the specific sense of that word. But I agree the form you show is accepted as the canonical representation for good reasons. In my interpretation, the OP's question was as much about how to handle lists of lists in that context as it was about BST specifically, if not more so. Therefore, I addressed the OP's question on that basis.

Comment: @mbratch indeed, and this is why I didn't claim that I answered his question.

Answer (score 1):

It look like each node in your tree is of the form:

`[left-subtree, header, right-subtree]`

If that is so, then if you have a tree `T`, and unify it with `[L,H,R]`, `L` will be the left subtree, `H` will be the header, and `R` will be the right subtree.

Comment: yeah , that's my idea , but i don't know how to deal with this type of list  , i tried to learn by coding something , but it does not give me any useful results !!

Comment: @Hassan you should show your coding attempt in your question.